# How to make sub menu float over div?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Hello all I have a sub menu that with a drop down menu but when the menu comes down it pushes the div below down. Any idea on how to fix so it loads over div?

and also one is horizontal and one is vertical how to fix that aswell 
thanks!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pc4xC/)

```
    <ul class="proda">
    <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="current">All Categories</a></li>

    <li><a>Styles</a><b class="caret2"></b>
            <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".slim">Slim</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".loose">loose</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".pro">proffesional</a></li>       
            </ul>               
    </li>

    <li><a>Brands</a><b class="caret2"></b>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".ses" class="current">LA Sesso</li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".isa" class="current">Issah</li>
        <li><a href="#" data-filter=".ant" class="current">Antonio</li>
      </ul>           
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".seas">Seasonal</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".bnew">New</a></li>
</ul>
.proda{
    display: table-row;
    list-style: none;
}


.proda li ul { 
    background: #ccc;
    display: none; 
}

.proda li{
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 15px;
} 

.proda li a:hover{
    color: blue;
}

.proda li:hover ul { 
    position: relative;
    display: block; 
    z-index: 1;
 }

    display: block;
    background-color: #ecf0f1;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.proda li:hover ul { 
    position: absolute; //Changed
    display: block; 
    z-index: 1;
 }
```

change this in your css

Comment: Worked Thanks, any idea how to make  it float above the div?

Comment: check the updated fiddle for your ans and make sure you mark your correct ans so that other users will get to know the ans

Comment: updated the fiddle you provided, i have marked my changes, now it'll be easy for you to c the cahnges

Comment: yes ofcourse, but do you know how to make the dropdown float over the div and not behind it? thanks

Comment: elaborate.. as in float over means how you want?

Comment: I solved it by adding padding between thelowest point of the dorpdown and the next div because the menu was droping behind the div

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is all wrong. Define a dropdown class:

```
.dropdown{
 position: absolute;
display: none;
z-index: 99;
width: 150px;
}
```

Then give your line that class:

```
    <li class="dropdown"><a>Brands</a><b ></b>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".ses" class="current">LA Sesso</li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".isa" class="current">Issah</li>
    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".ant" class="current">Antonio</li>
  </ul>           
</li>
```

And appropriately rearrange your navigation. Also, please use the `nav` tag.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
.proda li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yoo must change `position` of sub-menu to `absolute`. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JdESr/)

Answer (score 0):

use position absolute for submenu ul

```
 proda li:hover ul {
 position: absolute;}
```

and position relative for menu li

```
proda li{ position: relative;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/akash4pj/pc4xC/5/

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pc4xC/7/)

Remove `position:relative`  from `.proda li:hover ul` instead use `position:absolute`.

So your  css code will be like following:

```
    .proda li:hover ul { 
        position: absolute;
        display: block; 
        z-index: 1;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change remove property `position: relative;` from your selector `.proda li:hover ul` to get

```
        .proda li:hover ul {
            display: block;
            z-index: 1;
        }
```

Then add this other selector

```
        .proda>li>ul{
            position: absolute;
        }
```