# Div not displaying correctly as submenu of a nav

Tags: html, css

Now the nav doesn't display as it should in this example when in full screen but it show correctly when in iPad mode on chrome, so for my purposes this will work.

I have totally made a submenu that pops out from the top nav before but for what ever reason this one has me stumped.

first I thought well duh! You need to change `hoverableMenu{position:absolute};`

and `hoverable{position:relative};`

and viola I would be done. However no matter what I do it either goes all the way to the left when I have `float:left;` and even if I wanted to I could hardcode the position using margin, but thats not an elegant solution and I know that in all honesty it is merely something that is flying over my head.

any and all help is appreciated.

Below is my minimum verifiable example.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
body{
margin: 0px;
background-color: lightblue;
height: 100%;
}
header{
    /*This is for the header picture background*/
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: url(resources/chem3D.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    /* vh = viewheight. Used in place of percentages when percentages don't seem to work. This is basically 30% but not really
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039979/css-units-what-is-the-difference-between-vh-vw-and */
    min-height: 100%; 
}
/*Seperate the header from the content*/
#seperator{
    height: 10px;
    background-color: black;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

/*THe main content of the site. Where the Flex magic happens.*/
#content{
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    height: auto;
}

/*Navigation Stuffs*/
nav{
    width: 200px;
}


.topnav{
    overflow: hidden;
}


/*style of links in nav*/
/* ADDED FLOAT LEFT */
.topnav a{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

/* Drop down menu */
a.hoverable:focus + div.hoverableMenu{
display: block;
float: left;
}

a.hoverable:hover{
    color:black;
}
div.hoverableMenu{
    display: none;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:10px;
}

div.hoverableMenu>a{
    letter-spacing: 0em;
}
div.hoverableMenu:focus{
    display: block;
}

/*Mobile views*/
 /*Tablet View*/
 @media screen and (max-width: 900px){
#seperator{
    display: none;
}
#content{
    height: 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

nav{
    width: 100%;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
.topnav a{
    float: left;
}

main{
    width: 50%;
}

header{
    display:none;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="seperator"></div>
<div id="content">
    <nav>
        <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">

            <a href="index.html">Home</a>
            <a href="teaching.html">Teaching</a>

            <a class="hoverable" href="#">Research <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="hoverableMenu">
                <a href="research.html">Overview</a>
                <a href="publications.html">Publications</a>
            </div>

            <a class="hoverable" href="#">Students <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="hoverableMenu">
                <a href="studentawards.html">Awards</a>
                <a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
            </div>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3xrntjbw/)

resources I accessed:

https://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/pdcAF/1/

[How to make sub menu float over div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24882692/how-to-make-sub-menu-float-over-div)

[Can't click on menu links in drop down menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39432813/cant-click-on-menu-links-in-drop-down-menu)

**EDIT**
Under my media query I change the following.

```
div.hoverable{
    display: relative;
}

div.hoverableMenu{
    float:right;
    display: absolute;
}

div.hoverable:focus > div.hoverableMenu{
    top:1em;
    left: 140px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

after doing this the menus are now popping up relative to their parents but they are causing the elements to the right of them to wrap around to under the rest of the nave items. Instead of the sub menu floating over the nav. :(

Comment: this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14340231/10295470) may help you

Comment: Thanks for your response. if I change [a.hoverable:focus + div.hoverableMenu] to [a.hoverable:focus > div.hoverableMenu] My menu wont activate at all. Maybe I am misunderstanding?

Comment: I changed div.hoverable{display: relative;} and div.hoverableMenu{display:absolute;}. Setting the top and left in the   a.hoverable:focus + div.hoverableMenu{} didn't net any change either.

Comment: I even added a rule div.hoverable:focus > div.hoverableMenu{top: 1em; left 140px;} trying to get the relative positioning to the parent element as described in the link and I still don't get the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your structure a bit to `ul li`, checkout the code below

```js
            function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
                if (x.className === "topnav") {
                    x.className += " responsive";
                } else {
                    x.className = "topnav";
                }
            }
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 100%;
    }
    header{
        /*This is for the header picture background*/
        background-size: 100%;
        background-image: url(resources/chem3D.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        /* vh = viewheight. Used in place of percentages when percentages don't seem to work. This is basically 30% but not really
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039979/css-units-what-is-the-difference-between-vh-vw-and */
        min-height: 100%; 
    }
    /*Seperate the header from the content*/
    #seperator{
        height: 10px;
        background-color: black;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    /*THe main content of the site. Where the Flex magic happens.*/
    #content{
        display: flex;
        margin: auto;
        height: auto;
    }

    /*Navigation Stuffs*/
    nav{
        width: 200px;
    }


    .topnav{
        overflow: hidden;
    }


    /*style of links in nav*/
    /* ADDED FLOAT LEFT */
    .topnav a{
        float: left;
        display: block;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 5px 10px 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    }

    /* Drop down menu */
    a.hoverable:focus + div.hoverableMenu{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    }

    a.hoverable:hover{
        color:black;
    }
    div.hoverableMenu{
        display: none;
        width: 70%;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:10px;
    }

    div.hoverableMenu>a{
        letter-spacing: 0em;
    }
    div.hoverableMenu:focus{
        display: block;
    }
    
    


/*//////////*/

.topnav{
  overflow: visible;
}
.topnav > li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.topnav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.topnav > li > ul {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 40px;
}

.topnav > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.topnav li {
}

.topnav:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}


/*//////////*/



    /*Mobile views*/
/*Tablet View*/
@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
    #seperator{
        display: none;
    }
    #content{
        height: 100%;
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    nav{
        width: 100%;
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
    .topnav a{
        float: left;
    }

    main{
        width: 50%;
    }

    header{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <div id="seperator"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <nav>
            
            <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="teaching.html">Teaching</a></li>
                
                <li><a class="hoverable" href="#">Research <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>

<ul class="hoverableMenu" style="
">
                    <li><a href="research.html">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="publications.html">Publications</a></li>
                </ul>
</li>
                
                
                <li><a class="hoverable" href="#">Students <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>

<ul class="hoverableMenu">
                    <li><a href="studentawards.html">Awards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                </ul>

</li>
                
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </a></li>
            </ul>
            
            
        </nav>
        <main>
        </main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: im going to go test this on my code. If this works for me you better prepare yourself for a big ol' green check mark bucko.

Comment: This works, except for when the menu is on the left side, and I can't select items in the drop down regardless.

Comment: I think I got it. The change that needed to happen was .topnav > li > ul {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 40px;
    z-index: 99;
}

.topnav > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    background-color:blue;
}

.topnav > li:hover + ul {
    display: block;
    background-color:blue;
}

Comment: glad you figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Change Some CSS

```js
function myFunction() {
                var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
                if (x.className === "topnav") {
                    x.className += " responsive";
                } else {
                    x.className = "topnav";
                }
            }
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 100%;
    }
    header{
        /*This is for the header picture background*/
        background-size: 100%;
        background-image: url(resources/chem3D.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        /* vh = viewheight. Used in place of percentages when percentages don't seem to work. This is basically 30% but not really
        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039979/css-units-what-is-the-difference-between-vh-vw-and */
        min-height: 100%; 
    }
    /*Seperate the header from the content*/
    #seperator{
        height: 10px;
        background-color: black;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    /*THe main content of the site. Where the Flex magic happens.*/
    #content{
        display: flex;
        margin: auto;
        height: auto;
    }

    /*Navigation Stuffs*/
    nav{
        width: 200px;
    }


    .topnav{
        overflow: hidden;
    }


    /*style of links in nav*/
    /* ADDED FLOAT LEFT */
    .topnav a{
        float: left;
        display: block;
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 5px 10px 15px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    }

    /* Drop down menu */
    a.hoverable:focus + div.hoverableMenu{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    }

    a.hoverable:hover{
        color:black;
    }
    div.hoverableMenu{
        display: none;
        width: 70%;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:10px;
    }

    div.hoverableMenu>a{
        letter-spacing: 0em;
    }
    div.hoverableMenu:focus{
        display: block;
    }
    
    


/*//////////*/

.topnav{
  overflow: visible;
}
.topnav > li {
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.topnav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.topnav > li > ul {
    display: none;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0px;
}

.topnav > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}

.topnav li {
}

.topnav:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}


/*//////////*/



    /*Mobile views*/
/*Tablet View*/
@media screen and (max-width: 900px){
    #seperator{
        display: none;
    }
    #content{
        height: 100%;
        display:flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    nav{
        width: 100%;
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
    .topnav a{
        float: left;
    }
.topnav > li > ul {
   
    left: 0%;
    padding: 0;
    top: 40px;
}
    main{
        width: 50%;
    }

    header{
        display:none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
    </header>
    <div id="seperator"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <nav>
            
            <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="teaching.html">Teaching</a></li>
                
                <li><a class="hoverable" href="#">Research <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>

<ul class="hoverableMenu" style="
">
                    <li><a href="research.html">Overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="publications.html">Publications</a></li>
                </ul>
</li>
                
                
                <li><a class="hoverable" href="#">Students <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>

<ul class="hoverableMenu">
                    <li><a href="studentawards.html">Awards</a></li>
                    <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                </ul>

</li>
                
                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                </a></li>
            </ul>
            
            
        </nav>
        <main>
        </main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```